# Parsing huge json object by object in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, parsing, stream

**Problem**

I have a json file consisting of a huge array of small json objects. Now, if I attempt to parse it by the conventional means, read the file to memory and then invoke any json parse on it (E.g. json.parse or Oj.parse) it will consume all my system available memory and wont finish.

**What I want?**

Some way to parse it by stream and every time it finishes an object it would call-back a function with the object. With this, I believe the memory usage would be very low and constant.

**What I accomplished so Far**

I checked two gems ([yajl](https://github.com/brianmario/yajl-ruby) and [json-stream](https://github.com/dgraham/json-stream)) and found the following solution using yajl:

```
def post_init
  @parser = Yajl::Parser.new(:symbolize_keys => true)
end

def object_parsed(obj)
  puts "Sometimes one pays most for the things one gets for nothing. - Albert Einstein"
  puts obj.inspect
end

def connection_completed
  # once a full JSON object has been parsed from the stream
  # object_parsed will be called, and passed the constructed object
  @parser.on_parse_complete = method(:object_parsed)
end

# Parse itself
post_init
connection_complete
@parse << File.read("data.json",2048)
```

But there still is a problem with this approach, the @parser.on_parse_complete is only triggered after the array is closed (thus after the json was completed parsed). But in the other hand, if I format the json with a object per line, it works fine and the function *object_parsed* is called twice, once per line.

**Json sample:**

```
[
  {
    "v": {
      "M0": 2
    },
    "dims": {
      "D371665580_86": "M77",
      "D2088848381_86": "M5",
      "D372510617_86": "M42"
    }
  },
  {
    "v": {
      "M0": 2
    },
    "dims": {
      "D371665580_86": "M77",
      "D2088848381_86": "M5",
      "D372510617_86": "M42"
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would forget about rules and go with the following approach:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'stringio' # for tests

input = '[{"menu": {
          "id": "file",
          "value": "File"
          }
  },
  {"menu": {
          "id": "file2",
          "value": "File2"
          }
  }]'

io = StringIO.new input # here a file stream is opened

loop.inject(counter: 0, string: '') do |acc|
  char = io.getc

  break if char.nil? # EOF
  next acc if acc[:counter].zero? && char != '{' # between objects

  acc[:string] << char

  if char == '}' && (acc[:counter] -= 1).zero?
    # ⇓⇓⇓ # CALLBACK, feel free to JSON.parse here
    puts acc[:string].gsub(/\p{Space}+/, ' ') 
    next {counter: 0, string: ''} # from scratch
  end

  acc.tap do |result|
    result[:counter] += 1 if char == '{'
  end
end

#⇒ {"menu": { "id": "file", "value": "File" } }
#  {"menu": { "id": "file2", "value": "File2" } }
```

Here we just read the stream byte by byte and as soon as the very closing curly bracket is met, we emit `puts`. This is efficient and bullet-proof, assuming you are concerned the input is an array, consisting of hashes.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @Jordan what’s wrong with an example you provided? It’s up to callback to decide what to do with malicious data. Do you expect any json parser will do smth meaningful with this type of input?

Comment: The input in my code isn't malicious data, it's 100% valid JSON. Any correct JSON parser will handle it just fine.

Comment: Oh, indeed, sorry. The additional check for “we are inside quotes” is required.

Comment: Then you also need to check for escaped quotes. There's a reason JSON parsers don't use regexes.

Comment: I know the reason JSON parsers don’t use regexps. OK, I failed with calling it “bullet-proof,” but for the goal of OP, not for academical research, this solution might be the best and easiest one. BTW, this approach does not use regexps. AFAIK, all stream parsers use the same approach, since building grammar / using visitors might be quite expensive on large input.